# Docker no module found

Tags: python, node.js, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy my node js web app. this contains one python file which I am calling from node using 'child-process'. I tried to deploy this in docker environment because some dependencies required by python is not present in python environment.

So, the project has been deployed successfully but when I tried to send the request where I need that python file to run, I am getting error as no module found...

I already installed all the libraries using docker still getting error.

Is there anyone know how to fix this ?

The docker code is :-

```
# Stage 1: Python build
FROM python:3.9 AS python_builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Python dependencies files to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the project files to the working directory
COPY . .

# Stage 2: Node.js runtime
FROM node:14

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the built Python application from the previous stage
COPY --from=python_builder . .

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json files to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install npm dependencies
RUN npm install

# Expose the port on which your Express application runs (replace 3000 with your desired port)
EXPOSE 8000

# Specify the command to run your application
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Help us help you - share the full error

Comment: You forgot to copy the express, I think is missing a `COPY` on node:14 stage